# Fetching Value From Json Object Stored as String for a Key in Response payload

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

How do I read a value from below response payload. From the second property in this JSON object, how do I fetch the value for the 'status' i.e "Active" or any other value for response key.

```
{
  "signature": "1hdj12493039282849922",
  "response": "{'UsersList':[{'userName':'Madan Jones','mobileNumber':'767780987','status':'Active','statusCode':null}],'status':0,'messageCode':null,'message':null,'errorMap':null}"
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!! Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Your `response` contains just a text that only looks like another json. So in order to do a check you have to fetch that value, parse it and hope that it would be a valid json too.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    String str = RestAssured
            .get("http://demo1954881.mockable.io/textjson")
            .jsonPath().get("response");
    JsonPath jsonPath = new JsonPath(str.replace("'", "\""));
    String status = jsonPath.get("UsersList.find{u -> u.userName = 'Madan Jones'}.status");
    MatcherAssert.assertThat(status, Matchers.equalTo("Active2"));
}
```

In your particular example `JsonPath` does not like that your field names are wrapped with `'` so I change them to be proper double-quotes.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. Appreciate your time taken to have a look into my issue. Thanks once again!!